# Optimizing "simplifier"

Tags: java, optimization, design-patterns

Basically, I'm trying to make a Simplifier that can take inputs in the form of a `String` and print out the solution step-by-step. Now that I've got it working, I think it has some cleanliness issues.

```
public static void test(String eqn) {
    char[] order = { '^', '*', '/', '+'};   //order of precendece
    int found, i, j;
    eqn = eqn.replace("-", "+-");       //Subtracting = Adding (-)ve number.
    eqn = eqn.replace(" ", "");         //Spaces can cause a lot of trouble.
    String eqnC, left, right;
    System.out.println("=>\t"+eqn);
    for(char op : order) {
        while ((found = eqn.indexOf(op)) > -1) {
            left = eqn.substring(0, found);
            right = eqn.substring(found + 1);
            //keep 'walking' up and down the String till a non-number encoutered.
            for( i = left.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                if(!isPONumber(left.charAt(i)))
                    break;
            for( j = 0; j < right.length(); j++)
                if(!isPONumber(right.charAt(j)))
                    break;
            double lV = Double.parseDouble(left.substring(++i));    //left operand
            double rV = Double.parseDouble(right.substring(0, j));  //right operand
            eqn = left.substring(0, i) + putV(lV, rV, op) + right.substring(j);
            System.out.println("=\t" + eqn);
        }
    }
}

private static String putV(double a, double b, char op) {
    switch(op) {
        case '^':   return Math.pow(a, b) + "";
        case '/':   return (a / b) + "";
        case '*':   return (a * b) + "";
        case '+':   return (a + b) + "";
    }
    return null;
}

/*
 * Limit (for now) : decimal support.
 */
private static boolean isPONumber(char c) {
    return Character.isDigit(c) || c == '.' || c == '-';
}
```

Here are some outputs:

```
=>  2*84/6+7^2
=   2*84/6+49.0
=   168.0/6+49.0
=   28.0+49.0
=   77.0

=>  3^3/3^2
=   27.0/3^2
=   27.0/9.0
=   3.0

=>  400^0.5
=   20.0
```

I'd be grateful if anyone would comment and criticize and help me to clean-up my code. I also invite suggestions for making it better, improvising it and so on.

Comment: @Jamal Thanks for the edit... (I see that you had edited my previous post as well, thanks for that too) :-)

Comment: No problem!  Feel free to change something back if an edit introduces misleading information (I don't think that's the case here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I love the replacement of `-` with `+-`. It's simple and effectful. I'd like to see a similar use of `*` and `/` by introducing an operator for the reciprocal, e.g. `~`. This would of course require using a custom function for parsing the numbers instead of `parseDouble` (or the introduction of real unary operators), so that may cancel out any advantages.

EDIT: Just like `a - b` is equal to `a + -b`, `a / b` is equal `a * 1/b`. `1/b` is called the [reciprocal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse) of `b`. You could define an operator (such as `~` or any other character, that you aren't using) to represent the reciprocal, and replace `/` with `*~`, so that `4/2` becomes `4*~2`. That requires you to add `~` as a valid character to `isPONumber`, and replace `parseDouble`since it doesn't know what `~` is (I just invented it). See next edit.

I'm not really a fan of using `parseDouble` directly anyway. I'd at least replace it with a custom function that possibly uses `parseDouble` internally.

EDIT: By using `parseDouble` you are saying "my programm uses the same syntax for number literals as Java". That is not a problem, until you realize that the Java syntax may not support every thing you need, for example because you just decided to support the reciprocal operator, or you want the program to be international and some countries use a comma  instead of a period for the decimal mark, e.g. `1,2` instead of `1.2`, but `parseDouble` doesn't support this. And instead of needing to search your whole code and replace each occurance of `parseDouble`, you should have one function

```
static public double parseNumber(String number) {
  return Double.parseDouble(number);
}
```

Now if you need to change the syntax of your numbers, then you only have one defined place where you need to do it. For example to support the reciprocal:

```
static public double parseNumber(String number) {
  if (number.charAt(0) == '~') {
    return 1 / parseNumber(number.substring(1));
  }
  return Double.parseDouble(number);
}
```

(END EDIT)

I also don't like the use of the variable names `i` and `j` here, since they are used outside the `for` loop. Something like `leftOffset`/`rightOffset` may be more appropriate.

You could drop the variables `left` and `right` and search the original string with `i` and `j` starting at `found`/`found + 1`.

The use of a `enum` for the operators would also be useful. Something like:

```
interface DoubleOperation {
  public double calc(double a, double b);
}

enum Operator {
  POWER("^", new DoubleOperation() { public double calc(double a, double b) { return Math.pow(a, b); } }),
  DIVISION("/", new DoubleOperation() { public double calc(double a, double b) { return a / b; } });
  // ...

  public String op; // Use private and a getter in real code
  public DoubleOperation calc;

  Operator(String op, DoubleOperation calc) {
    this.op = op;
    this.calc = calc;
  }
}
```

(Look into the just released JDK 8 for [lamba expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to simplify this.)

Comment: And what do you mean by _similar use of * and / by introducing an operator for the reciprocal_? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Don't dismiss rofl's answer. All his remarks are correct too (except regarding the scope of `i`/`j`). My remarks are just additions. I'll do some edits to expand on your comments.

Comment: No, I didn't dismiss off @rofl's answer, I applied his `ArrayList<>` approach. So I guess it's _Bye bye offset_! But how do I _apply_ the `enum`? Should I use an enhanced `for-loop` for this?

Comment: Also (after reading your approach about reciprocals) is it really efficient? I mean, we'll have to divide it anyway... why add [extra] overhead?

Comment: No. Forget the reciprocals. It was just a wild idea that jumped into my head :-)

Answer (score 4):

### Algorithm

The algorithm works well enough. You have captured the essence of the problem in your code, and reading your code it is apparent what it does, and why.

This is a good thing. It is not very often that the intent of the code is so easy to discern.

The draw-back of your algorithm is that it is not going to be able to support the more esoteric operations like parenthesis e.g. `( 123 - 45 ) ^ 2` .... That sort of support will require a preprocessing step.

Keeping the equation as a string is convenient for some things, but i would have preferred to see the process broken down in to components, for example, a parse step could break the input down to `List<String> eqnParts = parse(eqn)`. at the same time, it could be trimming the white-space. Then, you just need to scan the `List<String>` and find 3 items separated by the highest precedence operator, and swap all three with the resulting value.

### Code Style

You should read through the [Code Style Guidelines for Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html).

This code, for example, [has a number of faults](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141388.html#682):

> ```
>         for( i = left.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
>             if(!isPONumber(left.charAt(i)))
>                 break;
>         for( j = 0; j < right.length(); j++)
>             if(!isPONumber(right.charAt(j)))
>                 break;
> ```

It should rather look something like:

```
        for (int i = left.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if(!isPONumber(left.charAt(i))) {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < right.length(); j++) {
            if(!isPONumber(right.charAt(j))) {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Notes:

1. declare `int i` and `int j` ***inside*** the loop.
2. space after the keyword `for`.
3. braces even for '1-liner' conditional statements.

### Double.parseDouble

`Double.parseDouble()` throws the unchecked exception `NumberFormatException`.

The exception thrown does not give great deals of information about why the number is not valid.

I always recommend wrapping Double.parseDouble (and `Integer.parseInteger()`, etc.) in a try-catch that reports what value was parsed, as well as the exception that was thrown. Otherwise debugging is a pain.

I often have a helper function like:

```
public static final double parseDouble(String value) {
    try {
        return Double.parseDouble(value);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to Double.parseDouble(" + value + ")", nfe);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only a _part_ of the real thing... I'll add the ability to detect brackets later. See [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/232875/should-a-calculator-support-curly-braces-and-box-braces) to understand what I mean.

Comment: I forgot to say thanks... As for the `NumberFormatException`, should I define a _custom_ `Exception` like `EquationError` or something?

Comment: @ambigram_maker Normally what I have is a helper function. I edited my answer to give an example.

Comment: @rolfl If he declares `i, j` in the for loop the program won't compile. He uses them in the next two lines.

Comment: @rofl The `try..catch` is not exactly what I want... I want to _throw_ an `Exception`, in case of ___any___ kind of error that may arise in this code (the full code I mean).

Comment: @ambigram_maker why not add a throws new Exception("more information") in the catch block, then?